# difference made by sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

[Problem statement link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/interviews/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=legacy&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Correct code ([by dongyuzhang](https://www.hackerrank.com/dongyuzhang?hr_r=1)):

```
select con.contest_id,
        con.hacker_id, 
        con.name, 
        sum(total_submissions), 
        sum(total_accepted_submissions), 
        sum(total_views), sum(total_unique_views)
from contests con 
join colleges col on con.contest_id = col.contest_id 
join challenges cha on  col.college_id = cha.college_id 
left join
(select challenge_id, sum(total_views) as total_views, sum(total_unique_views) as total_unique_views
from view_stats group by challenge_id) vs on cha.challenge_id = vs.challenge_id 
left join
(select challenge_id, sum(total_submissions) as total_submissions, sum(total_accepted_submissions) as total_accepted_submissions from submission_stats group by challenge_id) ss on cha.challenge_id = ss.challenge_id
    group by con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name
        having sum(total_submissions)!=0 or 
                sum(total_accepted_submissions)!=0 or
                sum(total_views)!=0 or
                sum(total_unique_views)!=0
            order by contest_id;
```

My changed code without sub-queries which is incorrect and giving larger values of sums. I don't understand how writing sub-queries is making the difference ? A simple example test case would be very helpful. THANKS !

```
select con.contest_id,
        con.hacker_id, 
        con.name, 
        sum(total_submissions), 
        sum(total_accepted_submissions), 
        sum(total_views), sum(total_unique_views)
    from contests con 
    join colleges col on con.contest_id = col.contest_id 
    join challenges cha on  col.college_id = cha.college_id 

        left join view_stats vs 
        on cha.challenge_id = vs.challenge_id 
        left join submission_stats ss
        on cha.challenge_id = ss.challenge_id

    group by con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name
    having sum(total_submissions)!=0 or 
    sum(total_accepted_submissions)!=0 or
    sum(total_views)!=0 or
    sum(total_unique_views)!=0
    order by contest_id;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? format text instead of image thanks

Comment: link to the problem statement has the sample data and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general with the subqueries first you make the aggregation before the join, so the values are right, since you have only one row per chalange_id respective contest_id and hacker id with the right sum.
If you join them together first, the values are summed up once for every matching row in the main-query.

Table1:

```
id | value1
 a | 1   
 a | 2
 b | 3
```

Table2:

```
id | value2
 a | 5
 a | 6
```

If you join without subqueries you got(before grouping)

```
a | 1 | 5
a | 1 | 6
a | 2 | 5
a | 2 | 6
```

So surely the sums are wrong.

```
select Table1.id , sum(value1), sum(value2) from
     Table1 join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
```

would return

```
 a | 6 | 22
```

but

```
select Table1.id , sum(value1), max(sum2) from
     Table1 join (select sum(value2) as sum2 from Table2 group by id) t2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
```

would return

```
  a | 3 | 11
```

I don't know if this is the case in your query, but this is the main difference of using subqueries

Comment: How did you join table 1 and table 2 ? what would be the result of adding them with sub-queries ?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: i used dublicate keys in both tables, with duplicate keys only in Table2 sum(sum2) would be ok

Comment: finally figured it out. Thank you so much!